# Group Slack Interactive Message Menus as a Form

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have successfully displayed two message menus (= dropdowns) alongside with a confirmation button in an interactive conversation in my App (See screenshot below).

[image: Slack Message Menus]

Each time a user interacts with one of the component (dropdowns or button), I get a request on the server side with the corresponding component information. But I would like to receive the whole content of the "form". Is there any way to group fields together?

It seems I could use Slack *dialogs* to do that but I prefer to keep it simple as an interactive conversation if possible.

Any tips?

Comment: I confirm, my question is indeed a duplicate of the above pointed one. It can be closed.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the duplicate request. Those often stay open a long time due to low traffic on this tag.